# What does a ">|"-redirection ("greater-pipe"-redirection) mean?

Tags: bash, shell, bourne-shell

What does the `>|`-redirection in bash do?

I just found out, that `echo text >| somefile` creates the file `somefile` (if not existing yet), and fills it with `text`. Similar as `echo text > somefile` would do.

Further experiments suggest that the `>|`-redirection behaves as the `>`-redirection does.

So, what is the `>|`-redirection exactly?

Since it's hard to google for the string ">|", I could not really search the web (so I have added "greater-pipe" in the title of this question since that is google-able).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the bash manual ([3.6.2 Redirecting Output](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output)):

> If the redirection operator is `>|`, or the redirection operator is `>` and
>   the `noclobber` option to the `set` builtin command is not enabled, the redirection is attempted even if the file named by *word* exists.